# Linking R.h Rembedded.h with C code

Tags: c, r, static-linking

I am including a few header files:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_machine.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_cblas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>

#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rembedded.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R_ext/Lapack.h>
#include <R_ext/Linpack.h>
```

I am able to link the blas and gsl libraries using the following command (the -lm is for math?):

`gcc -arch x86_64 myfile.c -o myfile -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas`

But I get error:

```
myfile.c:21:15: error: R.h: No such file or directory
myfile.c:22:19: error: Rmath.h: No such file or directory
myfile.c:23:23: error: Rembedded.h: No such file or directory
myfile.c:24:22: error: Rdefines.h: No such file or directory
myfile.c:25:26: error: R_ext/Lapack.h: No such file or directory
myfile.c:26:27: error: R_ext/Linpack.h: No such file or directory
```

How do I link the header files when compiling my C code?

Answer (score 0):

Header files aren't linked, only included. The errors mean just what they say: the compiler can't find them. Make sure they are in the standard include directory. Maybe you didn't `make install` the R library. If the header files are in the same directory as your other source files include them with double-quotes instead of angle brackets:

```
#include "R.h"
```

You can add other directories to the list of standard include directories with the [`-I` flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) to GCC.